# VS 2015 to VS 2017 - rdlc not working anymore

Tags: c#, .net, report

I'm facing some issue when I started to use VS 2017 instead of VS 2015.
When i open a report .rdlc on VS 2017, a textbox tell me to upgrade my report :

> Do yo uwant to convert this file to the most recent RLDC ?

If i click **No**, i can't modify my report.
If i click **Yes**, i can modify my report. But when i launch my app with this report i got an error saying:

> "Definition of report "" is not valid" - "An error has occured..."

I've already tried to uninstall then reinstall **RDLCDesigner** and **ReportingServices**

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you have any update ?